# Middleware Route Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to access my dashboard just after I logged. What's the problem ?

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {


        Route::get('/login', function () {
            return view('login');
        })->name('home');

        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('welcome');
        });


        Route::post('/signup',[
            'uses' => 'UserController@SignUp',
            'as' => 'signup'
        ]);

        Route::post('/signin',[
            'uses' => 'UserController@SignIn',
            'as' => 'signin'
        ]);

        Route::get('/dashboard',[
            'uses' => 'UserController@dashboard',
            'as' => 'dashboard',
            'middleware' => 'auth'
        ]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to be redirected to dashboard right after login You can set redirect path in `AuthController`.

Look for `protected $redirectTo = '/';` line and change it to `protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';` or add it if it does not exists in `AuthController`.

Comment: redirection works. if the user is not logged, be blocked dashboard page

Answer (score 0):

I have never had a problem with login in laravel 5.2. I used laravel's authentication and it worked fine all the time.

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication
2. Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
     // put your routes here

   });
3. add this in every controller you have: public function __construct() { $this->middleware('auth'); }